# reading output of a child process Interruptibly

Tags: java, process, pipe

I want to launch a child proces and read its output until EOF or until an internal flag is cleared.

My first attempt was to call `InputStream.close()` in another thread, but although it works for sockets, it doesn't work with the result of `Process.getInputStream()`: the main thread is still waiting in `read()` and the killer thread either hangs in `close0()` (windows) or continues with no effect (linux).

Then I tried to check `InputStream.available()`, but it doesn't detect EOF: it returns 0.

```
public class BbbTest extends TestCase {

    private Process proc;
    private InputStream getStream() throws IOException {

        //if ("".length() == 0) return new java.net.Socket("intra", 80).getInputStream();

        String[] cmd;
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows")) {
            cmd = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "more & more" };
        } else {
            cmd = new String[] { "sh", "-c", "cat; cat" };
        }
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        return proc.getInputStream();
    }

    public void testB() throws Exception {
        final InputStream in = getStream();
        final Thread readingThread = Thread.currentThread();
        Thread t = new Thread("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                    if (proc != null) proc.destroy(); // this won't help
                    readingThread.interrupt(); // this won't help either
                    in.close(); // this will do nothing and may even hang
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException ( );
                }
            }
        };
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

        try {
            in.read();
            assertTrue(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // nothing
        }
    }
}
```

My last hope is to steal the channel from the returned stream and use nio

Comment: You want to read the content the other process writing in stream or do you want to kill the process

Comment: @Mani srsly, "I want to launch a child proces and read its output"

Comment: Then why are trying to kill / close the stream. and the command you ar e executing will not terminate it self ( more & more )

Comment: @Mani It's just an example. I don't mind if it's killed, but the main goal is to quit read()

Comment: Please see my answer. if you want to read you can read using that.

Answer (score 0):

In windows , this Command will not terminate.

```
 cmd = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "more & more" };
```

Instead of try this simple command

```
 cmd = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "dir" };
```

And if you want to read your stream

```
public static void slurp(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize)
    {
        try(final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);){
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Call this method by passing stream like this.

```
final BbbTest bbTest = new BbbTest();
    Thread t = new Thread("xsdfds") {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        slurp(bbTest.getStream());
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException ( );
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
```

If you want to kill the process from child thread.
Create setter and getter method for Process in BbbTest like this

```
public class BbbTest {

    private Process proc;

    /**
     * @return the proc
     */
    public Process getProc() {
        return proc;
    }

    /**
     * @param proc the proc to set
     */
    public void setProc(Process proc) {
        this.proc = proc;
    }
        private InputStream getStream() throws IOException {
        String[] cmd;
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows")) {
            //  cmd = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "more & more" };
            cmd = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "dir" };
        } else {
            cmd = new String[] { "sh", "-c", "cat; cat" };
        }
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        return proc.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

Now using process you can destroy

```
bbTest.getProc().destroy();
```

If you want to kill the process based on output of other stream, you can add logic in slurp method by checking line content and terminate using destroy

```
UPDATE
```

Simple Demo

```
public class BbbTest {


    private Process startProcess(String[] commands) throws IOException {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        return proc;
    }

    public static void slurp(final InputStream is)
    {
        try(final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);){
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line.equals("end")){
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final BbbTest bbTest = new BbbTest();
        final Process process = bbTest.startProcess(new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "more" });
        Thread t = new Thread("xsdfds") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    slurp(process.getInputStream());
                    process.destroy();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException ( );
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

        try(OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
                BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);){
            outStream.write("Test".getBytes());
            outStream.write("\n".getBytes());
            outStream.write("end".getBytes());
            outStream.write("\n".getBytes());
            outStream.flush();
        }


    }
}
```

Look at this sample : You should have some condition to terminate the child thread ( reading prcoess) like if the stream writes "end" / or End of EOF ( process closed inputstream )

Comment: "In windows , this Command will not terminate." - that's the point! I can't accept your answer, because it can't stop reading from a process that cannot be terminated

Comment: What you mean. You need to have condition to stop ( either EOF - in your case it is not EOF ) or based on output

Comment: Check my last note. if you are not interested to wait until EOF then you have to condition. like if stream writing end/exit/terminate you should destroy

Comment: destroy won't kill the whole tree and thus won't close their end of the pipe